# How to check if a string starts and ends with specific strings?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like:

```
string str = "https://abce/MyTest";
```

I want to check if the particular string starts with `https://` and ends with `/MyTest`.

How can I acheive that?

Comment: Are u sure u want //MyTest? This doesn't seem like a valid url.

Comment: Do you care about case? Can it be `mytest`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This regular expression:

```
^https://.*/MyTest$
```

will do what you ask.

`^` matches the beginning of the string.

`https://` will match exactly that.

`.*` will match any number of characters (the `*` part) of any kind (the `.` part). If you want to make sure there is at least one character in the middle, use `.+` instead.

`/MyTest` matches exactly that.

`$` matches the end of the string.

To verify the match, use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^https://.*/MyTest$");
```

More info at the MSDN [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) page.

Comment: @Steve3000: Finally! I spent the last three hours being "beaten to it" :)

Comment: Don't see why this isn't the accepted answer, was first and correct!

Comment: @Stevo: thanks for the support. Actually it is not completely correct. There is an extra slash somewhere. Will fix...

Comment: @Stevo3000: It was indeed correct, though mine provided the actual code required to run the match (and was probably higher voted for this reason). Seems the OP switched his accepted answer, anyway. :P

Comment: @Noldorin: you are right. My code was added later on, when I noticed the .net tag. FWIW I had upvoted you before.

Comment: @Noldorin - I upvoted you too as you were the first to show the .NET syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
var str = "https://abce/MyTest";
var match = Regex.IsMatch(str, "^https://.+/MyTest$");
```

The `^` identifier matches the start of the string, while the `$` identifier matches the end of the string. The `.+` bit simply means any sequence of chars (except a null sequence).

You need to import the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace for this, of course.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to check if the particular string starts with "https://" and ends with "/MyTest".

Well, you *could* use regex for that. But it's clearer (and probably quicker) to just [say what you mean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx):

```
str.StartsWith("https://") && str.EndsWith("/MyTest")
```

You then don't have to worry about whether any of the characters in your match strings need escaping in regex. (For this example, they don't.)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET:

```
^https://.*/MyTest$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htmhttp://), good for building .NET regexes and teaching you the syntax at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

HAndy tool for genrating regular expressions

http://txt2re.com/